# recursive backtracking algorithm that counts all solutions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

I'm building a sudoku generator-solver app and currently finishing the hiding algorithm for useless cells.

I have a working backtracking algorithm that returns true when the solution is found, but I need to check if there're any other solutions to prevent a wrong board from creating.

findEmpty function finds the next empty cell inside a sudoku board.
isValid function checks if the parameter passed fits in a current cell.
Provided code returns true if the board is solved.
It does overwrite the passed variable, so to access a solved board I call the variable passed.

If there's at least one extra solution, the function must return false.
If the board cannot be solved, the function must return false.
If there's a solution(only 1), return true

```
function backTrackSolve(board)
  {
      let find = findEmpty(board)
      if (find[0] == -1)
          return true
      
      let row = find[0]
      let col = find[1]
  
  
      for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      {
  
          if (isValid(board, { row,col }, i))
          {
              board[row][col] = i
              if (backTrackSolve(board)){
                    return true
              }
  
            }
              board[row][col] = 0
      }
  
      return false
  
  }
```

Comment: Hi voq, what are you asking? So far you have only made statements, and it is unclear what you need help with.

Comment: @CVerica I am asking how to make it find all solutions, not just one

Comment: Hey voq, if the only thing you struggle with is to find all solutions just look on your base case when all the grid is finished (if (find[0] == -1) return true)  and instead return true just save the grid/count it and return false and continue searching until the end.

Comment: @JackRaBeat thanks, that helped.  don't know why I didn't figure that out

Comment: But note that you really want to stop when you hit a second one, so you don't simply want to find all solutions.  Imagine trying that on an empty board!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function backTrackSolve(board)
      {
          let find = findEmpty(board)
          if (find[0] == -1){
              //count stuff here
              return false;
          }
          let row = find[0]
          let col = find[1]
      
      
          for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++)
          {
      
              if (isValid(board, { row,col }, i))
              {
                  board[row][col] = i
                  if (backTrackSolve(board)){
                        return true
                  }
      
                }
                  board[row][col] = 0
          }
      
          return false
      
     }
```